# Excel - Check if a date range overlaps only if a cell is a duplicate

Tags: excel, date, range

We are using a spreadsheet to act as a booking sheet for some iPads at work.

I'd like to be able to easily check whether an iPad has been booked out on a date range. I can do this if the start date is the same by using this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($C$4:$C$1000,C4,$E$4:$E$1000,E4)>1,"Double Booked","")
```

- Column C is the ID of the iPads
- Column E is the "Start Date"

However I'd like to extend this to check for any date between the start and end date.

Here is an image of how the spreadsheet is laid out, with the non relevant stuff redacted; is there a way to do this?

[Screenshot of my spreadsheet with non relevant information redacted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teEVn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that column E (Start Date) is always less than or equal to column F (End Date), this will work. There may be a simpler way of doing this though.

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIFS($C$4:$C$1000,C4,$E$4:$E$1000,"<="&E4,$F$4:$F$1000,">="&E4)>1,COUNTIFS($C$4:$C$1000,C4,$E$4:$E$1000,"<="&F4,$F$4:$F$1000,">="&F4)>1),"Double Booked","")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was missing the >1 at the end of the 2nd Countifs but I've added it making it:  `=IF(OR(COUNTIFS($C$4:$C$1000,C4,$E$4:$E$1000,"<="&E4,$F$4:$F$1000,">="&E4)>1,COUNTIFS($C$4:$C$1000,C4,$E$4:$E$1000,"<="&F4,$F$4:$F$1000,">="&F4)>1),"Double Booked","")`